synced scrollbars move themselves
I somehow implemented synced scrollbars
note.tsx:
"use client";

import { useState, useCallback, useRef, useEffect, use } from "react";
import Editor from "./components/editor/editor";
import Preview from "./components/preview/preview";
import { ViewMode } from "./types";
import { Container, NoteResizer, ResizerColumn } from "./style";
import Header from "./components/header/header";

const Note = () => {
  const [doc, setDoc] = useState<string>("# Hello, World!\n");
  const [mode, setMode] = useState<ViewMode>(ViewMode.Middle);
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(50);
  const [mouseDown, setMouseDown] = useState(false);
  const [cursorStyle, setCursorStyle] = useState("auto");
  const [left, setLeft] = useState(0);
  const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false);

  const menuSize = {
    min: 20,
    max: 80,
  };

  const handleDocChange = useCallback((newDoc: string) => {
    setDoc(newDoc);
  }, []);

  const handleMouseDown = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    setMouseDown(true);
    setCursorStyle("col-resize");
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  const handleMouseUp = () => {
    setMouseDown(false);
    setCursorStyle("auto");
  };

  const handleMouseMove = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    if (mouseDown) {
      const container = event.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
      const newWidth = Math.min(
        ((event.pageX - container.left - 3.5) / container.width) * 100,
        menuSize.max
      );
      if (newWidth > menuSize.min) {
        setWidth(newWidth);
      }
      if (editorRef.current) {
        let bc = editorRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
        setLeft(bc.left + bc.width - 5);
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      if (editorRef.current) {
        let bc = editorRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
        setLeft(bc.left + bc.width - 10);
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    };
  }, []);

  const firstDivRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>();
  const secondDivRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>();
  const editorRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>();

  const firstCont = useRef<HTMLDivElement>();
  const secondCont = useRef<HTMLDivElement>();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (editorRef.current) {
      let bc = editorRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
      setLeft(bc.left + bc.width - 10);
    }
  }, [editorRef.current, mode]);

  const debouncedHandleScrollFirst = (scroll: any) => {
    if (
      firstDivRef.current &&
      secondCont.current &&
      firstCont.current &&
      secondDivRef.current
    ) {
      secondDivRef.current.scrollTop =
        ((scroll.target as HTMLDivElement).scrollTop /
          firstCont.current.getBoundingClientRect().height) *
        secondCont.current.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    }
  };

  const debouncedHandleScrollSecond = (scroll: any) => {
    if (
      firstDivRef.current &&
      secondCont.current &&
      firstCont.current &&
      secondDivRef.current
    ) {
      firstDivRef.current.scrollTop =
        ((scroll.target as HTMLDivElement).scrollTop /
          secondCont.current.getBoundingClientRect().height) *
        firstCont.current.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Header setMode={setMode} mode={mode} setWidth={setWidth} />
      <Container
        onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
        onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
        $cursorStyle={cursorStyle}
      >
        <Editor
          onChange={handleDocChange}
          onScroll={debouncedHandleScrollFirst}
          initialDoc={doc}
          mode={mode}
          width={width}
          reference={firstDivRef}
          reference2={editorRef}
          reference3={firstCont}
          left={left}
        />
        {mode == ViewMode.Middle && (
          <NoteResizer onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}>
            <ResizerColumn />
          </NoteResizer>
        )}
        <Preview
          doc={doc}
          mode={mode}
          onScroll={debouncedHandleScrollSecond}
          reference={secondDivRef}
          isClicked={isClicked}
          setIsClicked={setIsClicked}
          reference2={secondCont}
        />
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default Note;

editor.tsx
import { EditorState } from "@codemirror/state";
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import useCodeMirror from "./useCodeMirror";
import { EditorWindow, Scroller, Thumb } from "./style";
import { ViewMode } from "../../types";

interface Props {
  initialDoc: string;
  mode: ViewMode;
  width: number;
  onChange: (doc: string) => void;
  onScroll: (scroll: Event) => void;
  reference: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | undefined>;
  reference2: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | undefined>;
  reference3: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | undefined>;
  left: number;
}

const Editor = (props: Props) => {
  const {
    onChange,
    initialDoc,
    mode,
    width,
    onScroll,
    reference,
    reference2,
    reference3,
    left,
  } = props;

  if (mode !== ViewMode.Preview) {
    const [thumbSize, setThumbSize] = useState(5000);
    const [distance, setDistance] = useState(0);
    const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false);
    const [startY, setStartY] = useState(0);
    const [startScrollTop, setStartScrollTop] = useState(0);

    const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | undefined>(null);
    const cntRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (!isDragging) {
        const handleScroll = (e: Event) => {
          if (containerRef.current && cntRef.current) {
            const mdHeight =
              containerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().height;
            const contHeight = cntRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().height;

            //console.log(contHeight * (contHeight / mdHeight));

            const distFromTop = (e.target as HTMLDivElement).scrollTop;

            setDistance((distFromTop / mdHeight) * (contHeight - 32));

            ///console.log(contHeight, mdHeight, distFromTop);
          }
        };

        if (reference.current) {
          reference.current.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

          return () => {
            if (reference.current) {
              reference.current.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
            }
          };
        }
      }
    }, [isDragging, thumbSize]);

    const changeThumbSize = () => {
      if (containerRef.current && cntRef.current) {
        const distFromTop =
          (containerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().top - 69) * -1;
        const contHeight = cntRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().height;
        const mdHeight = containerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().height;

        setThumbSize(contHeight * (contHeight / mdHeight));

        setDistance((distFromTop / mdHeight) * (contHeight - 12));
      }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      const handleMouseMove = (e: MouseEvent) => {
        if (
          !isDragging ||
          !cntRef.current ||
          !containerRef.current ||
          !reference.current
        )
          return;

        const tPos = distance;
        const contHeight = containerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().height;
        const mdHeight = cntRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().height;
        const newDistance = Math.min(
          Math.max(tPos + (e.clientY - startY) - thumbSize, 0),
          mdHeight - thumbSize - 12
        );

        if (e.clientY != startY) {
          setDistance(newDistance);
          setStartY(newDistance);
        }

        reference.current.scrollTop = (newDistance / mdHeight) * contHeight;
      };

      const handleMouseUp = () => {
        console.log("mouse up");
        setIsDragging(false);
      };

      document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
      document.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);

      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
        document.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
      };
    }, [isDragging, startY, startScrollTop, thumbSize, distance]);

    const handleMouseDown = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
      setIsDragging(true);
      console.log(isDragging);
      setStartY(e.clientY);
      if (reference.current) {
        setStartScrollTop(reference.current.scrollTop);
      }
    };

    const scrollBarClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
      const newDistance = e.clientY - 57 - thumbSize / 2;

      if (containerRef.current && cntRef.current && reference.current) {
        const contHeight = cntRef.current.clientHeight;
        const mdHeight = containerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().height;
        reference.current.scrollTop = (newDistance / contHeight) * mdHeight;

        setDistance(
          Math.min(
            Math.max(newDistance, 0),
            containerRef.current.clientHeight - thumbSize
          )
        );
      }
    };

    const handleChange = useCallback(
      (state: EditorState) => {
        onChange(state.doc.toString());
        changeThumbSize();
      },
      [onChange]
    );
    const [refContainer, editorView] = useCodeMirror<HTMLDivElement>({
      initialDoc,
      onChange: handleChange,
      onScroll: onScroll,
      reference2: containerRef,
      reference: reference,
      reference3: reference3,
    });

    return (
      <EditorWindow
        $mode={mode}
        $width={width}
        ref={(node) => {
          if (refContainer && node && reference2 && cntRef) {
            refContainer.current = node;
            reference2.current = node;
            cntRef.current = node;
          }
        }}
      >
        <Scroller onClick={scrollBarClick} $left={left}>
          {thumbSize < (containerRef.current?.clientHeight || 600) && (
            <Thumb
              $height={thumbSize}
              $distance={distance}
              onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
            />
          )}
        </Scroller>
      </EditorWindow>
    );
  }
};

export default Editor;

codemirror:
import { MutableRefObject, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { defaultKeymap, history, historyKeymap } from "@codemirror/commands";
import { EditorState } from "@codemirror/state";
import {
  EditorView,
  keymap,
  highlightActiveLine,
  lineNumbers,
  highlightActiveLineGutter,
  drawSelection,
} from "@codemirror/view";
import {
  syntaxHighlighting,
  HighlightStyle,
  indentOnInput,
  bracketMatching,
} from "@codemirror/language";
import { tags } from "@lezer/highlight";
import { markdown, markdownLanguage } from "@codemirror/lang-markdown";
import { languages } from "@codemirror/language-data";
import { oneDark } from "@codemirror/theme-one-dark";
import { vim, Vim } from "@replit/codemirror-vim";

interface Props {
  initialDoc: string;
  onChange?: (state: EditorState) => void;
  onScroll: (scroll: Event) => void;
  reference: MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | undefined>;
  reference2: MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | undefined | null>;
  reference3: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | undefined>;
}

const transparentTheme = EditorView.theme({
  "&": {
    backgroundColor: "transparent !important",
    height: "100%",
  },
});

const syntaxHighlightingCustom = HighlightStyle.define([
  {
    tag: tags.heading1,
    fontSize: "1.6em",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  {
    tag: tags.heading2,
    fontSize: "1.4em",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  {
    tag: tags.heading3,
    fontSize: "1.2em",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
]);

const useCodeMirror = <T extends Element>(
  props: Props
): [MutableRefObject<T | null>, EditorView?] => {
  const refContainer = useRef<T>(null);
  const [editorView, setEditorView] = useState<EditorView>();
  //const { onChange, onScroll, reference, onScroll2, reference2 } = props;
  const { onChange, onScroll, reference, reference2, reference3 } = props;
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!refContainer.current) return;

    const startState = EditorState.create({
      doc: props.initialDoc,
      extensions: [
        vim(),
        keymap.of([...defaultKeymap, ...historyKeymap]),
        lineNumbers(),
        highlightActiveLineGutter(),
        history(),
        indentOnInput(),
        bracketMatching(),
        highlightActiveLine(),
        drawSelection(),
        markdown({
          base: markdownLanguage,
          codeLanguages: languages,
          addKeymap: true,
        }),
        oneDark,
        transparentTheme,
        syntaxHighlighting(syntaxHighlightingCustom),
        EditorView.lineWrapping,
        EditorView.updateListener.of((update) => {
          if (update.changes) {
            onChange && onChange(update.state);
          }
        }),
      ],
    });

    Vim.map(":", "<Esc>");

    const view = new EditorView({
      state: startState,
      parent: refContainer.current,
    });

    const scroller = view.dom.querySelector(".cm-scroller");
    if (reference && scroller) {
      reference.current = scroller as HTMLDivElement;
      scroller.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
      // scroller.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll2);
    }

    const container = view.dom.querySelector(".cm-content");
    if (reference2 && container && reference3) {
      reference2.current = container as HTMLDivElement;
      reference3.current = container as HTMLDivElement;
    }

    setEditorView(view);

    return () => {
      view.destroy();
    };
  }, [refContainer]);

  return [refContainer, editorView];
};

export default useCodeMirror;


preview.tsx:
import { createElement, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { unified } from "unified";
import remarkParse from "remark-parse";
import remarkGfm from "remark-gfm";
import remarkReact from "remark-react/lib";
import { PreviewWindow, Scroller, Thumb } from "./style";
import RemarkCode from "./remarkCode";
import { defaultSchema } from "hast-util-sanitize";
import "github-markdown-css/github-markdown.css";
import { ViewMode } from "../../types";

interface Props {
  doc: string;
  mode: ViewMode;
  onScroll: (scroll: React.UIEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => void;
  reference: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | undefined>;
  reference2: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | undefined>;
  setIsClicked: (isClicked: boolean) => void;
  isClicked: boolean;
}

const schema = {
  ...defaultSchema,
  attributes: {
    ...defaultSchema.attributes,
    code: [...(defaultSchema.attributes?.code || []), "className"],
  },
};

const Preview = (props: Props) => {
  const {
    doc,
    mode,
    onScroll,
    reference,
    setIsClicked,
    isClicked,
    reference2,
  } = props;

  if (mode !== ViewMode.Edit) {
    const mdContainerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
    const ContainerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
    const [thumbSize, setThumbSize] = useState(5000);
    const [distance, setDistance] = useState(0);

    const handleScroll = () => {
      if (mdContainerRef.current && ContainerRef.current && !isDragging) {
        const distFromTop =
          (mdContainerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().top - 69) * -1;
        const contHeight = ContainerRef.current.clientHeight;
        const mdHeight = mdContainerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().height;

        setDistance((distFromTop / mdHeight) * (contHeight - 32));
      }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      if (mdContainerRef.current) {
        const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
          for (let _ of entries) {
            if (mdContainerRef.current && ContainerRef.current) {
              const distFromTop =
                (mdContainerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().top - 69) * -1;
              const contHeight = ContainerRef.current.clientHeight;
              const mdHeight =
                mdContainerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().height;

              setThumbSize(contHeight * (contHeight / mdHeight));

              setDistance((distFromTop / mdHeight) * (contHeight - 12));
            }
          }
        });

        resizeObserver.observe(mdContainerRef.current);

        return () => resizeObserver.disconnect();
      }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (mdContainerRef.current) {
        mdContainerRef.current.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
      }

      return () => {
        if (mdContainerRef.current) {
          mdContainerRef.current.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
        }
      };
    }, []);

    const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false);
    const [startY, setStartY] = useState(0);
    const [startScrollTop, setStartScrollTop] = useState(0);

    const handleMouseDown = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
      setIsDragging(true);
      setStartY(e.clientY);
      if (mdContainerRef.current) {
        setStartScrollTop(mdContainerRef.current.scrollTop);
      }
    };

    const handleMouseUp = () => {
      setIsDragging(false);
    };

    const scrollBarClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
      const newDistance = e.clientY - 57 - thumbSize / 2;

      if (ContainerRef.current && mdContainerRef.current) {
        const contHeight = ContainerRef.current.clientHeight;
        const mdHeight = mdContainerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().height;
        ContainerRef.current.scrollTop = (newDistance / contHeight) * mdHeight;

        setDistance(
          Math.min(
            Math.max(newDistance, 0),
            ContainerRef.current.clientHeight - thumbSize
          )
        );
        setIsClicked(true);
      }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      const handleMouseMove = (e: MouseEvent) => {
        if (!isDragging) return;
        if (mdContainerRef.current && ContainerRef.current) {
          const tPos = distance;
          const contHeight = ContainerRef.current.clientHeight;
          const mdHeight =
            mdContainerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().height;
          const newDistance = Math.min(
            Math.max(tPos + (e.clientY - startY) - thumbSize, 0),
            contHeight - thumbSize - 12
          );

          if (e.clientY != startY) {
            setDistance(newDistance);
            setStartY(newDistance);
          }

          ContainerRef.current.scrollTop =
            (newDistance / contHeight) * mdHeight;
        }
      };

      document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
      document.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);

      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
        document.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
      };
    }, [isDragging, startY, startScrollTop, thumbSize, distance]);

    const md = unified()
      .use(remarkParse)
      .use(remarkGfm)
      .use(remarkReact, {
        createElement: createElement,
        sanitize: schema,
        remarkReactComponents: {
          code: RemarkCode,
        },
      } as any)
      .processSync(doc).result;

    return (
      <PreviewWindow
        className="markdown-body editor"
        onScroll={(e) => {
          onScroll(e);
          handleScroll();
        }}
        ref={(node) => {
          if (reference && node) {
            reference.current = node;
            ContainerRef.current = node;
          }
        }}
      >
        <Scroller onClick={scrollBarClick}>
          {thumbSize < (ContainerRef.current?.clientHeight || 600) && (
            <Thumb
              $height={thumbSize}
              $distance={distance}
              onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
            />
          )}
        </Scroller>
        <div
          ref={(node) => {
            if (mdContainerRef && node && reference2) {
              mdContainerRef.current = node;
              reference2.current = node;
            }
          }}
        >
          {md as any}
        </div>
      </PreviewWindow>
    );
  }
};

export default Preview;

but the problem is that when i start to scroll, they continue to scroll by themselves and i'm not sure how to fix it, i think it happens because im trying to sync them based on height but sync in not correct and they break
so i need somehow stop infinite loop between scrollbars

It's missing some dependencies, can you make a runnable example here https://playcode.io/react or https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-new?
